# Move multiple table rows to another table without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I display the table from db. and i have checkbox for each row,I want to move the selected rows from one table to another "selected table" from the page without page refresh. ? the current selection has to be removed from current table. I can do the query like select * from tab-1 where id=$selected. and also can move it to another table with insert into tab_name and so on. but dont know how to do it without refresh and with some nice effects ? may be with jquery any pointers or help.

```
<table id="tab-1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Select</th>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">A</th>
        <th scope="col">B</th>
        <th scope="col">C</th>
        <th scope="col">D</th>
        <th scope="col">E</th>
        <th scope="col">E</th>
        <th scope="col">F</th>
        <th scope="col">G</th>
        <th scope="col">H</th>
        <th scope="col">I</th>
        <th scope="col">J</th>
        <th scope="col">k</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"  /></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['A']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['B']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['D']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['E']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['F']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['G']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['H']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['I']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['J']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['K']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['L']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['M']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery , Ajax you can do this .

```
<script>
    $('.checkBox').change(function() {
       var selected = $(this).val();
       $.post('yourfile.php' , {
         selected : selected
       } , function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    });

    $('.checkBox').mousedown(function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).trigger("change");
        }
    });
</script>
```

in `yourfile.php` you can execute SELECT and INSERT queries